# Возможно ли написать универстальную (для backend и frontend) функцию для задания абсолютного пути? Как это сделать?

Tags: php, frontend, backend

Если напишу вот так:

```
define('ROOT', $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

то при использовании функции на стороне сервера, например, imagejpeg, возникает ошибка:

```
 imagejpeg(http://mysite/files/users/imgs/original/man.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
```

Если напишу вот так:

```
define('ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

То во front-end'e (во view) картинка просто не откроется. Вот, например, такой код:

```
<div style="background-image:url('D:\1Develop\domains\mysite\files/users/imgs/original/man.jpg')"></div>
```

Блок с background-image пустой. Однако если взять путь, который в url, и вставить его в адресную строку, то картинка откроется.

Возможно ли написать универсальную функцию, которая будет работать и во front-end, и в back-end? Или нужно отправлять параметр $side, и в зависимости от него выбирать ROOT?

Если что, вот функция php, которая путь возвращает:

```
return DOCROOT . 'files/users/imgs/original/' . $user->photo;
```

Comment: Надо начать с того что на клиенте __нет__ абсолютного пути. Затем надо запилить две константы и не забивать себе голову.

Comment: А вот это разве не относительный путь? define('ROOT', $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'); Работает ведь.
Получится больше, чем две константы. Мне нужно, например, не к original, а к 122x122 (у меня есть такая папка). Это ведь еще одна константа? А если делать разные константы для сервера и клиента, то не одна, а целых две. Разве это нормально?

Comment: Я просто не понимаю - ну напишите функцию, передавайте в нее параметр каждый раз `$side`, сколько раз вызовете - столько лишних оверхедов на вызов функции получите. Объявив же две константы, обращения к ним будут сразу заменены на их значения, что снизит загрузку.

Comment: Я про другое. Я хочу указать одно значение (одну константу) вместо двух. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Очевидно, что невозможно.